# Marking multiple points on google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I wrote the following code. Please let me know, why it marks only 10 of these addresses?? All of the addresses are valid.

```
for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
  var x1;
  var y1;
  var point;
  adr = addr[i]; /// addr is a array includes 15 valid addresses   
  geocoder.getLatLng(adr, function(point) {
    if (!point) {
      alert(adr + " not found");
    }
    else {
      var marker = new GMarker(point);
      map.addOverlay(marker);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Please format your code next time; I did it for you so that I could read your post.

Comment: ok.....I got it......It's because google map geocoding limitation.....

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure that people who see this question in the future understands the answer.

He was trying to use the geocoder to get latlngs for 15 different addresses. This is a problem because there is a limit on how many requests you can make to Google Maps in a certain amount of time. After you have made 10 requests you reach the limit and have to wait before doing more requests.

The geocoder always returns a code to mark what status the response has, and if it is OVER_QUERY_LIMIT you have to wait. If it is SUCCESS then you can continue.